# php simple database iteration

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that contain a 'folder id' and the parent of that folder 'parent_id', by  default root folders have 'parent_id = 0'

```
---------------------------
| folder_id |   parent_id |
---------------------------
| 12        |   7
| 11        |   9
| 6         |   0
| 7         |   6
| 8         |   7
| 9         |   0 
| 10        |   0
```

i want to know how many children in a given folder.

when i try a recursion function like this:

```
public function getSubFolder($fo_id , $totalSubFolders = 0){
    $q = $this->db->select('*')->from('folder')->where('parentid' , $fo_id)->get();
    if($q->num_rows()> 0){
        foreach ($q->result() as $folder) {

           $parentid = $folder->fo_id;

           $totalSubFolders++;
           $this->getSubFolder($parentid , $totalSubFolders);

        }

    }
 echo $totalSubFolders;

}
```

when i call this function 'getSubFolder(6)' the output is 2331,

I don't know why please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi the result should be 3 right? i mean if you pass 6 then
 for 6 we have 7 and for 7 we have 12 and 8 so total sub folder for 6 -> 7, 8, 12 = 3 right??

you do not need to change the below code check it out.. declare the $totalSubFolders as public nt take it as private variable otherwise it will create the problem check the below code

```
$totalSubFolders = 0;

public function getSubFolder($fo_id)
{
    $q = $this->db->select('*')->from('folder')->where('parentid' , $fo_id)->get();
    if($q->num_rows()> 0)
    {
        foreach ($q->result() as $folder)
        {    
           $parentid = $folder->fo_id;    
           $totalSubFolders++;
           $this->getSubFolder($parentid);    
        }    
    }    
}

//now call the function as 

public function otherFunction()
{
    $this->getSubFolder(6);
    echo $totalSubFolder;
}
```

its working code i have tried..

Comment: actually whats happening because of ur **echo** at last line print the value of totalSubFolder at every end of the loop and print the value so it print 2 thn 3 thn 3 thn 1 and togethr it seems like 2331

Comment: :) ur welcome @ArhHokagi dont forget to say +1 so that other people can find its useful.. :)

Comment: actually i can't +1'd your answer, because i must have at least 15 point in my reputation

Answer (score 0):

You're echoing your output, not adding it to the previous value.

```
public function getSubFolder($fo_id , $totalSubFolders = 0){
    $q = $this->db->select('*')->from('folder')->where('parentid' , $fo_id)->get();
    if($q->num_rows()> 0){
        foreach ($q->result() as $folder) {

           $parentid = $folder->fo_id;

           $totalSubFolders++;
           $totalSubFolders = $this->getSubFolder($parentid , $totalSubFolders);

        }

    }
    return $totalSubFolders;
}

public function otherFunction() {
    echo $this->getSubFolder(6);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this before i post my question here, the output is 1

Comment: I think in this case u will get the answer as 1 for 6 right? am i right @ArhHokagi??